# Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, nodemcu

i am having problem connecting to the firebase library.. i am using arduino ide 1.8.13 and nodemcu esp8266.. i got this error message ....can someone help me solve this problem..

```
C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp: In member function 'virtual void FirebaseHttpClientEsp8266::begin(const string&)':
C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:50: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(const char*, const char [60])'
   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);
      |                                                  ^
In file included from C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:
C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:166:10: note: candidate: 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, uint16_t, String)' (near match)
  166 |     bool begin(String host, uint16_t port, String uri = "/")  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClient, host, port, uri)")));
      |          ^~~~~
C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:166:10: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} [-fpermissive]
   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                              |
      |                              const char*
In file included from C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:
C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:167:10: note: candidate: 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, const uint8_t*)' (near match)
  167 |     bool begin(String url, const uint8_t httpsFingerprint[20])  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClientSecure, ...)")));
      |          ^~~~~
C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:167:10: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} [-fpermissive]
   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                              |
      |                              const char*
C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp: In member function 'virtual void FirebaseHttpClientEsp8266::begin(const string&, const string&)':
C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:51:60: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} [-fpermissive]
   51 |     http_.begin(host.c_str(), kFirebasePort, path.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);
      |                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                            |
      |                                                            const char*
In file included from C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:
C:\Users\Nurul_Aida\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.0\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:168:70: note:   initializing argument 4 of 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, uint16_t, String, const uint8_t*)'
  168 |     bool begin(String host, uint16_t port, String uri, const uint8_t httpsFingerprint[20])  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClientSecure, ...)")));
      |                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

Comment: Could you please include the code you're using as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should try and contact the Author of the Firebase-arduino project and see if they have updated their libraries. I'm seeing multiple faults for conversion types and obsolete API.

I would suggest looking at the Firebase Documentation and look at their [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) solutions rather than relying on 3rd party libraries that are deprecated.